# What are the workarounds for returning variables number of columns from dynamic sql to entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, return

So I have stored procedure which has some dynamic sql and it returns the calculated values. The returned result set though can be of variable columns.

So, now the problem is I want to add this procedure to entity framework 4 and I don't think its going to support it.So, now one way to do it would be creating temporary tables or table valued variables will kind of help but we don't want to go that way.

Have anyone of you come across this problem? What are the workarounds for such a situation. I basically want to return variable number of columns from a stored procedure and somehow map it to a complex type in entity framework ?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is that you have to modify your SP to always return all possible columns, and you use placeholders for any that aren't present. For example, if your SP returns col1, col2 and col3 in one scenario, and col1, col2, col4 and col5 in another scenario, then you need to always return col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5, and use dummy values (null or empty string, for example) for the columns that you don't have values for. E.g.

```
SELECT col1
     , null as col2
     , col3
 ...
```

The thing to remember about EF is that when it generates the complex type, it basically calls your SP and passes null for all the parameters. Whatever result set gets returned is what EF is going to use when creating the complex type.

We've found this one of the more frustrating things with EF.